# When constructor argument that's heap allocated throws c++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

In [Effective C++](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html) item 17, there's an example where a function call may leak:

```
processWidget (std::tr1::shared_ptr<Widget> ( new Widget ), priority ());
```

According to the book, the leak happens if new widget is first created. Then priority is called, but it throws, and in this case the shared pointer was never created and new Widget is leaked.

To my understanding a call like this would not leak:

```
processWidget (std::tr1::shared_ptr<Widget> ( new Widget ));
```

But in this case, what if new Widget throws, why there's no memory leak? Or is the only safe way to do this ( and if so, how's that different? )

```
auto w = std::tr1::shared_ptr<Widget> ( new Widget );
processWidget ( w );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `new Widget` throws then the memory is automatically freed (if it got as far as allocating it); so the second example is fine.

However, it's a good idea to use `make_shared` anyway, since it makes more efficient use of memory by just allocating a single block for both the object and the reference count.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. I understood that this won't leak, but how does it actually work? the smart pointer takes the newed object as argument, so if the new throws, then how does the smart pointer get constructed with this argument?

Comment: @KJS: If `new` throws, then the smart pointer isn't constructed at all; the program jumps to the `catch` block before that would happen.

Comment: but in this case, wouldn't the new widget leak, since the smart pointer was responsible for releasing that?

Comment: @KJS: The new-expression itself is responsible for freeing the memory if it fails. There can only be a leak if something throws *after* the new-expression completes but *before* the smart pointer takes ownership. That can happen in the first example, but not the second.

Comment: Ok that sorts it out. Thanks again!